# Does ets provide a means to do an Update & Read in one go - like an Increment Operation?

Tags: erlang, increment, ets

I initialize a named ets table in my **start(_StartType, _StartArgs) ->** function, before setting up my standard Cowboy web handling routines.

ets:new(**req_stats**,[named_table,public]),ets:insert(req_stats,{**req_count**,0})

I have this function:

```
 count_req()->
    [{_,Cnt}]=ets:lookup(req_stats,req_count),
    ets:insert(req_stats,Cnt+1),
    Cnt+1.
```

My concern is this;

If i call count_req() for each web request under high load, i WILL most likely end up with an inaccurate count, because **[{_,Cnt}]=ets:lookup(req_stats,req_count)** could be updated several times before I return Cnt+1

Does ets provide a means to do an update & read in one go - like an increment operation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [ets:update_counter/3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html#update_counter-3):

```
ets:update_counter(req_stats, req_count, {2, 1})
```

That is, increment the 2nd element of the tuple by 1, and return the new value.

---

In Erlang/OTP 18.0 (released on 2015-06-24), `ets:update_counter/4` was introduced.  It lets you provide a default value, to be used if the key is not yet present in the table.  So if you want the counter to become 1 after the first time you increment it, give 0 as the default value:

```
1> ets:new(req_stats, [named_table]).
req_stats
2> ets:tab2list(req_stats).
[]
3> ets:update_counter(req_stats, req_count, {2, 1}, {req_count, 0}).
1
4> ets:tab2list(req_stats).
[{req_count,1}]
```

Comment: Thanks! just one quick edit, the ets table has to be public for my approach to work, other than that update_counter works fine.

Comment: Just wanted to check if it's possible to also insert a Key with default, value. Or how update_counter with Default works

Comment: @OlegTarasenko It wasn't possible when I first wrote the answer, but now it is :) I updated the answer with an example.